# Typescript promise must be handled properly

Tags: typescript, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I has the following to update my firestore document. But there is an error saying that promise must be handled properly. I already added in try catch in my function..Can anyone advise what else I missed out?

```
export const updateCustomer = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, resp) => {
    try
    {
            await db.collection('Users').where('CompanyId', '==', req.body.CompanyId)
            .where('CustomerId', '==', req.body.CustomerId)
            .get()
            .then(snapshot => {   
                 snapshot.forEach(doc => 
                     {
                         db.collection('Users').doc(doc.id).update(
                             {
                                 CustomerName : req.body.CustomerName,
                                 MobileNo : req.body.MobileNo,
                                 DOB: req.body.DateOfBirth,
                                 Email : req.body.Email,
                                 PreferredLanguage: req.body.PreferredLanguage
                             }
                         )
                     })
            })
            .catch(error => resp.status(500).send(error));   



       resp.status(200).send(req.body);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
       console.error(error);
       resp.status(500).send({ Message: error, StatusCode: '500', Status: 'Error'});
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`db.collection('Users').doc(doc.id).update()` returns a promise, and your code is ignoring it.  An HTTP type function should only return a result after all asynchronous calls are fully complete.  Putting a try/catch around the whole thing will not help.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how can I amend my codes?

Comment: Collect all the promises into an array and use Promise.all() to run some code only after they all resolve.

Comment: Do as @DougStevenson says but also don't forget to return the aggregated promise from your .then() and don't mix async/await with .then() syntax. Starting from where you are right now, the simpler option is probably to purge async/await and end up with `return db.collection()......get().then().then().catch();` That final catch is the only one you need.